# when i can pass intent for going another acvity then this type error generate

Tags: android

I can not pass intent another activity. When I do then error is thrown.

[image]

My code is:

```
public class Intro extends Activity
{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);

        ImageConfig.init(this);
        Setting.INSTANCE.initialize(this);
        PhotoDeskFragment.initMutiWindow();


        if (FolderFragment.getFolderItems() != null) {
            photoDeskActivity();
            return;
        }
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            loading();
        }
    }
    private void loading() {
        if (FolderFragment.isItemEmpty()) {
            ProtectUtil.getInstance().initialize(this);
            HiddenFolderUtil.getInstance().initialize(this);
            loadFolderItems();
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                if (mFuture != null) {
                    mFuture.waitDone();
                }photoDeskActivity();
            }
        }, ITEM_LOADING_TIME);
    }
    private void loadFolderItems() {
        mFuture = getThreadPool().submit(new LoadFolderItems(), new FutureListener<ArrayList<FolderItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onFutureDone(Future<ArrayList<FolderItem>> future) {
                FolderFragment.insertFolderItems(future.get());
                FolderFragment.runImageLoaderThread(getContentResolver());
            }
        });
    }
    public void photoDeskActivity()
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intro.this, PhotoDeskActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your code to help you

Comment: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);
        
        ImageConfig.init(this);
        Setting.INSTANCE.initialize(this);
        PhotoDeskFragment.initMutiWindow();
        
        
        if (FolderFragment.getFolderItems() != null) {
         photoDeskActivity();
         return;
        }
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         loading();
     }
 }

Comment: Please update your question

Comment: when i call  photoDeskActivity(); at that time generate error

Comment: Can you update complete code in the question?

Comment: Are you using Instant Run? Instant Run doesn't always behave the best with class changes.